# Raspberry Pi OSError: libbcm_host.so

Tags: picamera

I am running a facial recognition project on Pi 4. When I run the code, I got this full error message:

```
 File "/home/rlu/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from picamera.exc import (
  File "/home/rlu/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 41, in <module>
    import picamera.mmal as mmal
  File "/home/rlu/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera/mmal.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .bcm_host import VCOS_UNSIGNED
  File "/home/rlu/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera/bcm_host.py", line 47, in <module>
    _lib = ct.CDLL('libbcm_host.so')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

```
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

OSError: libbcm_host.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can someone please help me? Can this be the picamera issue? I am using the latest raspberry pi OS.

Comment: picamera isn't supported on 64bit os..... still... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71787870/oserror-libmmal-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-w